# How to display the last (n) of streams (links) from a user using the Mixer Api

Tags: ajax, api, stream, endpoint, mixer

TLTR:

From this (https://mixer.com/api/v1/channels/44877492/recordings) api endpoint I receive this value:

id: 302772586 (for example)

but the value that I need is this one:

https://mixer.com/CalypsoVibes?vod=2ArYJv4YfEaJezssnJR15Q

Where CalypsoVibes is the name of the user (I put the id that I return from another endpoint (channels/) and the vod id is something different from an integer.

Long story (not short):

I'm building a section to display the past (n) streams with their link from a user using the Mixer api.

Let's start saying that I didn't even know the existence of that website, so it has been really challenging to understand what data I need.

Here's my script and then I will explain the functionality:

```
$(() => {
    let mixerAPI = 'https://mixer.com/api/v1/';
    let streamName = 'GrimlockePrime';
    let apiCall = mixerAPI + "channels/" + streamName;

    function makeAjaxCall(url, methodType, callback){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : url,
            method :  methodType,
            dataType : "json",
            success : callback,
            error : function (reason, xhr){
                console.log("error in processing your request",reason);
            }
        })
    }
    makeAjaxCall(apiCall, "GET", function(respJson){
        console.log(respJson.id);
        let streamscall = mixerAPI + "recordings/165804890";
        console.log(streamscall);
        
    })

});
```

From this point, I will make another ajax call, using the id of the user's channel and put it in the record endpoint, to obtain this structure:

https://mixer.com/api/v1/recordings/channelId

The idea is to collect the last (n) streams from a user.

So, starting from a user profile on mixer.com, for example https://mixer.com/CalypsoVibes, I want to collect the last (n) number of streams, which are at the bottom of that section and are called "Past streams".

All of the resources has this structure

https://mixer.com/CalypsoVibes?vod=um8Nx4dNnUqj8E0jcDXKEw

so I probably need the vod id (?vod=id).

Oddly enough, I wasn't able to find any reference of that in the mixer api documentation. So I'm not 100% that I'm looking for the right endpoint.

There are a couple of them that could make the job:

1.https://mixer.com/api/v1/channels/userId/recordings
2.https://mixer.com/api/v1/recordings/id

Both of them will return vod values, but with a caveat which is the fact that they won't return any id or any useful link:

https://vodcontent-6001.xboxlive.com/channel-46362-public/7200a34f-7eca-4f81-822f-677afd4a8d97/

that's just an example of a return, but the id at the end of the url won't match any link from the app.

Does anyone ever had this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VoDs on Mixer have an `id`, which is an integer, and they have a `contentId` (introduced with Season 2 and the [v2 API](https://dev.mixer.com/guides/core/whatsv2)), which is a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (or GUID, if you prefer). UUIDs can also be represented as base64 strings and this is what the VoD ID in the link to a VoD on Mixer.com is using.
In your example `2ArYJv4YfEaJezssnJR15Q` is the same as `26d80ad8-18fe-467c-897b-3b2c9c9475e5`.
If you have this ID you can then request [`GET` `/vods/{contentId}`](https://dev.mixer.com/rest/index.html#vods__contentId__get) on the v2 API, which contains the various formats in the `contentLocators` object field in the JSON response. They're descriptive and include the complete URL to video and thumbnail content, but the VoD chat log is missing.

You can also use the older v1 API. Personally, that's what I'd recommend.
For any given channel, you would first make a request to [`GET` `/channels/{channelIdOrToken}`](https://dev.mixer.com/rest/index.html#channels__channelIdOrToken__get) to then grab the *channel ID* from the `id` property of the JSON response. Then you make a request to [`GET` `/channels/{channelId}/recordings`](https://dev.mixer.com/rest/index.html#channels__channelId__recordings_get), passing a query string of `where=state:eq:AVAILABLE&order=createdAt:desc` (pick only those which are available, not processing or already deleted, and order them most recent to oldest) to grab a list of VoD stream recordings. Append the [`Recording`](https://dev.mixer.com/rest/index.html#Recording)s in the response to a list, then examine the `X-Total-Count` HTTP response header, and if it is greater than 50, and you have gotten a response of 50 items, add a `page` query string parameter with a page counter and increment by one (from a default of `0`) and repeat the process until you have gotten them all.
You can then take your list of recordings and examine the `vods` object field on each of them. There should be 4 items, each with a `format` field of `hls`, `thumbnail`, `raw`, or `chat`.
You would grab the `baseUrl` of each, and append the following filenames to get their corresponding files:

- `hls`: `source.m3u8` (contains further references to actual transport stream files which are also found at this `baseUrl`, but you probably don't want to deal with that)
- `thumbnail`: `source.png`, if the `data.Has720pPreview` property is `true`, also `720p.jpg`
- `raw`: `source.mp4` (this is the file that is offered to you on the website as a download option on your own channel, or on all channels for users with the `Staff`, `Founder`, or `Guardian` roles)
- `chat`: `source.json` (this is a timestamped chat log, it includes all messages that have not been deleted, as well as user join and leave events)

You can find an example making use of the v1 API to embed the 50 newest VoDs from [LevelUpCast](https://mixer.com/LevelUpCast) into jPlayer *[here](https://www.nightmarejoker2.com/MixerVodEmbed/demo.html)*.

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $form = $('#vod-form');
    $form.on('submit', function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var channel = $form.find('input[name="channel"]').val();
        var beamApiBase = 'https://mixer.com/api/v1';
        var channelToken;
        var channelId;
        
        var vodListArray = [];
        function getVod(page)
        {
            $.ajax({ 
                url: beamApiBase + '/channels/' + channelId + '/recordings?where=state:eq:AVAILABLE&order=createdAt:desc&page=' + page,
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (data[i].state != 'AVAILABLE') // API is silly sometimes and ignores the query... ‍♀️
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        var thatVod = data[i];
                        var vodPaths = {
                            stream: null,
                            thumbnail: null,
                            small_thumbnail: null,
                            snapshot: null,
                            download: null,
                            chatlog: null
                        };
                        for (var j = 0; j < thatVod.vods.length; j++)
                        {   
                            var thisVod = thatVod.vods[j];
                            switch (thisVod.format)
                            {
                                case 'hls':
                                {
                                    vodPaths.stream = thisVod.baseUrl + 'manifest.m3u8';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 'thumbnail':
                                {
                                    vodPaths.thumbnail = thisVod.baseUrl + 'source.png';
                                    if (thisVod.data.Has720pPreview)
                                    {
                                        vodPaths.snapshot = thisVod.baseUrl + '720.jpg';
                                        vodPaths.small_thumbnail = thisVod.baseUrl + '168p.png';
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 'raw':
                                {
                                    vodPaths.download = thisVod.baseUrl + 'source.mp4';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 'chat':
                                {
                                    vodPaths.chatlog = thisVod.baseUrl + 'source.json';
                                    break;
                                }
                                default:
                                {
                                    console.warn('Unknown VoD format', thisVod);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        data[i].vodPaths = vodPaths;
                        var thisVodItem = {
                            'title': thatVod.name,
                            'artist': channelToken,
                            'date': new Date(Date.parse(thatVod.createdAt)),
                            'duration': thatVod.duration + 's',
                            'urls': vodPaths
                        };
                        vodListArray.push(thisVodItem);
                    }
                    if (data.length == 50 && xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Total-Count")*1 > 50)
                    {
                        getVod(page + 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (vodListArray.length > 0)
                        {
                            var $vodList = $('#vod-list');
                            var $table = $('<table>');
                            var $tableTitleRow = $('<tr>');
                            var $tableItemNumberColumn = $('<th>');
                            $tableItemNumberColumn.text('Item #');
                            $tableTitleRow.append($tableItemNumberColumn);
                            var $tableThumbnailColumn = $('<th>');
                            $tableThumbnailColumn.text('Small Thumbnail');
                            $tableTitleRow.append($tableThumbnailColumn);
                            var $tableTitleColumn = $('<th>');
                            $tableTitleColumn.text('Title/Name');
                            $tableTitleRow.append($tableTitleColumn);
                            var $tableDateColumn = $('<th>');
                            $tableDateColumn.text('Date');
                            $tableTitleRow.append($tableDateColumn);
                            var $tableLinksColumn = $('<th>');
                            $tableLinksColumn.text('Links');
                            $tableTitleRow.append($tableLinksColumn);
                            $table.append($tableTitleRow);
                            for (var i = 0; i < vodListArray.length; i++)
                            {
                                var $tableRow = $('<tr>');
                                var $tableColumnItemNumber = $('<td>');
                                $tableColumnItemNumber.text(i + 1);
                                $tableRow.append($tableColumnItemNumber);
                                var $tableColumnThumbnail = $('<td>');
                                var $thumbnail = $('<img>');
                                $thumbnail.attr('src', vodListArray[i].urls.small_thumbnail);
                                $tableColumnThumbnail.append($thumbnail);
                                $tableRow.append($tableColumnThumbnail);
                                var $tableColumnTitle = $('<td>');
                                $tableColumnTitle.text(vodListArray[i].title);
                                $tableRow.append($tableColumnTitle);
                                var $tableColumnDate = $('<td>');
                                $tableColumnDate.text(vodListArray[i].date.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + vodListArray[i].date.toLocaleTimeString());
                                $tableRow.append($tableColumnDate);
                                var $tableColumnLinks = $('<td>');
                                var $streamLink = $('<a>');
                                $streamLink.text("HLS Stream");
                                $streamLink.attr('href', vodListArray[i].urls.stream);
                                var $videoLink = $('<a>');
                                $videoLink.text("Video Download");
                                $videoLink.attr('href', vodListArray[i].urls.download);
                                var $chatLogLink = $('<a>');
                                $chatLogLink.text("Chat Log");
                                $chatLogLink.attr('href', vodListArray[i].urls.chatlog);
                                var $thumbnailLink = $('<a>');
                                $thumbnailLink.text("Thumbnail");
                                $thumbnailLink.attr('href', vodListArray[i].urls.thumbnail);
                                $tableColumnLinks.append($streamLink)
                                $tableColumnLinks.append($('<br>'));
                                $tableColumnLinks.append($videoLink);
                                $tableColumnLinks.append($('<br>'));
                                $tableColumnLinks.append($chatLogLink);
                                $tableColumnLinks.append($('<br>'));
                                $tableColumnLinks.append($thumbnailLink);
                                $tableRow.append($tableColumnLinks);
                                $table.append($tableRow);
                            }
                            $vodList.empty();
                            $vodList.append($table);
                        }
                    }
                }});
        }
        $.getJSON(beamApiBase + '/channels/' + channel, function (data)
        {
            channelToken = data.token;
            channelId = data.id;
            getVod(0);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
body
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
table, tr, th, td
{
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://zeptojs.com/zepto.min.js"></script>
<form id="vod-form">
    Channel Name or ID: <input type="text" name="channel" length="20"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Get list"></input>
</form>
<div id="vod-list">
    <p>The list will appear here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me try the snippet, as soon as I will make it work I will give you the bounty

Comment: I didn't find a way to make the v2 api works. I was able to use the id, essentially it is concerned to my example, but I wasn't able to get the right query

Comment: can you indicate a way to make the v2 works? or an example?

Comment: The v2 API at `/vods/{contentIdOrShareableId}` is only useful for retrieving a specific VoD by ID. You have to know this VoDs `contentId` (uuid) or `shareableId` (base64 encoded uuid v4 bytes). 
Since what you want is a list of download links, use the v1 API to grab a list of VoDs. Because the v1 API already provides the content URLs, except for the small 168p thumbnail, of which you can just assume it exists at the `thumbnail` `baseUrl` + `168p.png`.

Comment: @MarcuzioDevelopuzio I have added a code snippet you can run right inside of this page, and all you need to do is enter the channel name of your choice into the form and hit enter to get your list.